# Detect cycle in directed Graph

Tags: node.js, algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

Recently had to detect recursions in a directed graph in code logic. My nodejs implementation feels complex and I am now wondering:

- Are there any problems with the code?
- Can we simplify it / make it more readable?

```js
const checkCyclic = (graph) => {
  const nodes = new Set(Object.keys(graph));
  const searchCycle = (trace, node) => {
    const cycleStartIdx = trace.indexOf(node);
    if (cycleStartIdx !== -1) {
      throw new Error(`Cycle detected: ${trace
        .slice(cycleStartIdx).concat(node).join(' <- ')}`);
    }
    if (nodes.delete(node) === true) {
      const nextTrace = trace.concat(node);
      graph[node].forEach((nextNode) => searchCycle(nextTrace, nextNode));
    }
  };
  while (nodes.size !== 0) {
    searchCycle([], nodes.values().next().value);
  }
};

checkCyclic({
  p1: ['p3'],
  p2: ['p1'],
  p3: ['p2']
});
// => Recursion detected: p1 <- p3 <- p2 <- p1

checkCyclic({
  p0: ['p1'],
  p1: ['p3'],
  p2: ['p1'],
  p3: ['p2']
});
// => Recursion detected: p1 <- p3 <- p2 <- p1

checkCyclic({
  p0: ['p0']
});
// => Cycle detected: p0 <- p0
```

For the curious, this is being used in [promise-pool-ext](https://github.com/blackflux/promise-pool-ext), which also contains tests.

Thank you very much for your feedback!

---

**Edit:** Played around and did the iterative implementation (looks even uglier!)

```js
module.exports = (G) => {
  const pending = new Set(Object.keys(G));
  while (pending.size !== 0) {
    const trace = [pending.values().next().value];
    const parentIdx = [0];
    pending.delete(trace[0]);

    while (trace.length !== 0) {
      const c = trace.length - 1;
      const parent = G[trace[c]][parentIdx[c]];
      if (parent !== undefined) {
        if (trace.includes(parent)) {
          throw new Error(`Cycle detected: ${trace
            .slice(trace.indexOf(parent)).concat(parent).join(' <- ')}`);
        }

        parentIdx[c] += 1;
        if (pending.delete(parent)) {
          trace.push(parent);
          parentIdx.push(0);
        }
      } else {
        trace.pop();
        parentIdx.pop();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I usually prefer iterative to recursive, but in this case it might not worth the readability trade-off. Any idea how to improve this implementation?

Comment: One option would be to write this iterative. However I'm not sure that would make it more readable

Comment: do you want the path or just to know if you have a cycle (cycle is the term, not "recursion") in your graph?

Comment: @grodzi Thanks for the clarification regarding naming. For debug purposes it is important to return the cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may shorten it a bit:

```js
function getCycle (G, n, path) {
  if (path.includes(n)) {
    throw `cycle ${path.slice(path.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
  }
  path.push(n)
  return G[n].forEach(next => getCycle(G, next, path.slice(0)))
}
function validate (G) {
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => getCycle(G, n, []))
}
validate({
  p1:['p2','p3','p4'],
  p2:['p3'],
  p3:['p0'],
  p0:[],
  p4:[]
})
console.log('ok')
validate({
  p1:['p2','p3','p4'],
  p2:['p3'],
  p3:['p0'],
  p0:[],
  p4:['p1']
})
```

Now this is not the most efficient since we:

- find on path which is an array and not a set (idem O(k) instead of O(1))
- do revisit vertices even though they have already been visited

Below a slightly more optimized version at the sake of readability?

```js
function getCycle (G, n, path, visited) {
  if (path.has(n)) {
    const v = [...path]
    throw `cycle ${v.slice(v.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
  }
  visited.add(n)
  path.add(n)
  return G[n].forEach(next => getCycle(G, next, new Set(path), visited))
}
function validate (G) {
  const visited = new Set()
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => {
    if (visited.has(n)) return
    getCycle(G, n, new Set(), visited)
  })
}


validate({
  p1:['p2','p3','p4'],
  p2:['p3'],
  p3:['p0'],
  p0:[],
  p4:[]
})
console.log('ok')
validate({
  p1:['p2','p3','p4'],
  p2:['p3'],
  p3:['p0'],
  p0:[],
  p4:['p1']
})
```

---

Regarding perfs, I have (cheaply) tried to reproduce and compare algos on the same graph G (generated by random-dag) with **50** nodes.

They seem to be equivalent.

```js
function checkCyclic (G) {
  const pending = new Set(Object.keys(G));
  while (pending.size !== 0) {
    const trace = [pending.values().next().value];
    const parentIdx = [0];
    pending.delete(trace[0]);

    while (trace.length !== 0) {
      const lastIdx = trace.length - 1;
      const parent = G[trace[lastIdx]][parentIdx[lastIdx]];
      if (parent === undefined) {
        trace.pop();
        parentIdx.pop();
      } else {
        if (trace.includes(parent)) {
          throw new Error(`cycle ${trace
            .slice(trace.indexOf(parent)).concat(parent).join('<-')}`);
        }
        parentIdx[lastIdx] += 1;
        if (pending.delete(parent)) {
          trace.push(parent);
          parentIdx.push(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function grodzi1(G) {
  function getCycle (G, n, path) {
    if (path.includes(n)) {
      throw `cycle ${path.slice(path.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
    }
    path.push(n)
    return G[n].forEach(next => getCycle(G, next, path.slice(0)))
  }
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => getCycle(G, n, []))
}
function grodzi2(G) {
  function getCycle (G, n, path, visited) {
    if (path.has(n)) {
      const v = [...path]
      throw `cycle ${v.slice(v.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
    }
    visited.add(n)
    path.add(n)
    return G[n].forEach(next => getCycle(G, next, new Set(path), visited))
  }
  const visited = new Set()
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => {
    if (visited.has(n)) return
    getCycle(G, n, new Set(), visited)
  })
}

// avoid copying the set
function grodziNoCopy(G) {
  function getCycle (G, n, path, visited) {
    if (path.has(n)) {
      const v = [...path]
      throw `cycle ${v.slice(v.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
    }
    visited.add(n)
    path.add(n)
    return G[n].forEach(next => {
      getCycle(G, next, path, visited)
      path.delete(next)
    })
  }
  const visited = new Set()
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => {
    if (visited.has(n)) return
    getCycle(G, n, new Set(), visited)
  })
}

// avoid visiting the already visited set of nodes
function grodziStopVisit(G) {
  function getCycle (G, n, path, visited) {
    if (path.has(n)) {
      const v = [...path]
      throw `cycle ${v.slice(v.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
    }
    if (visited.has(n)) return
    visited.add(n)
    path.add(n)
    return G[n].forEach(next => {
      getCycle(G, next, path, visited)
      path.delete(next)
    })
  }
  const visited = new Set()
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => {
    if (visited.has(n)) return
    getCycle(G, n, new Set(), visited)
  })
}

// same but iterative
function grodziIter(G) {
  function dfs (G, n, visited) {
    let stack = [{ path: [], n }]
    let x
    while (x = stack.pop()) {
      const {n, path} = x
      if (path.includes(n)) {
        const v = [...path]
        throw `cycle ${v.slice(v.indexOf(n)).concat(n).join('<-')}`
      }
      if (visited.has(n)) continue
      visited.add(n)
      path.push(n)
      G[n].forEach(next => stack.push({ path: path.slice(0), n: next }))
    }
  }
  const visited = new Set()
  Object.keys(G).forEach(n => visited.has(n) || dfs(G, n, visited))
}

const G = {"0":["5","6","12","15","18","30","31","32","33","35","39","41","52","54"],"1":["12","17","29","30","34","35","38","39","40","43","53"],"2":["5","7","12","13","14","15","16","19","21","31","35","36","37","40","41","53"],"3":["14","16","15","30","32","40","52","55"],"4":["5","6","13","15","17","18","32","35","40","41","42","51"],"5":["16","15","30","33","52","53","55"],"6":["11","16","18","33","36","37","42","51","53"],"7":["14","15","16","22","30","33","35","36","39","41","43","49","53","54","55"],"8":["31","36","41","51"],"9":["18","30","36","37","39","40","50","52"],"10":["15","17","18","19","31","32","33","35","37","40","41","48","54","55"],"11":["15","17","19","31","32","35","38","41","40","43","48","52"],"12":["17","21","32","33","35","52","54","55"],"13":["18","19","20","29","33","35","36","38","41","43","52"],"14":["16","17","19","35","39","55"],"15":["20","22","30","33","35","38","39","41","42","43","49","50","54"],"16":["20","32","34","36","37","39","40","42","44","53"],"17":["28","31","36","35","38","41","43","44","48"],"18":["19","31","34","36","35","38","41","49","52","53","55"],"19":["29","36","48","51"],"20":["29","32","33","36","37","49"],"21":["30","31","33","34","35","36","39","48"],"22":["30","31","32","34","36","37","41","43","48"],"23":["33","34","35","36","37","40","44","50"],"24":["28","34","35","36","38","41","42","48","52"],"25":["28","29","31","32","36","41","43","53"],"26":["29","35","37","38","39","41","43","50"],"27":["31","35","36","37","41","42","48","51","53"],"28":["35","37","38","40","41","50","55"],"29":["38","39","40","42","44","51","54"],"30":["37","38","40","41","42","43","49","50","53"],"31":["36","39","40","50","52","54"],"32":["37","38","39","41","44","48","49","52","55"],"33":["41","40","42","44","52","53"],"34":["35","36","41","42","49","52","54"],"35":["44","55"],"36":["41","50","52","53","54"],"37":["52","55"],"38":["55"],"39":["40","41","51"],"40":["48","49","52"],"41":["49","52","53"],"42":["53"],"43":["48","50","52","55"],"44":["48","52","54"],"45":["49","53","54"],"46":["49","50","52"],"47":["48","50","52","53","55"],"48":[],"49":[],"50":[],"51":[],"52":[],"53":[],"54":[],"55":[]}
function bench (fn, label) {
  console.time(label)
  for (let idx = 0; idx < 50; idx += 1) { fn(G) }
  console.timeEnd(label)
}
function shouldThrow (...fns) {
  const cyc = {"p1":["p2","p3","p4"],"p2":["p3"],"p3":["p0"],"p0":[],"p4":["p1"]}
  fns.forEach(fn => {
    let ok = false
    try { fn(cyc) } catch (e) {
      ok = e.toString().includes('cycle p1<-p4<-p1')
      if(!ok){
        throw new Error('failzed ', e)
      }
    }
    if (!ok){ throw 'should have thrown' }
  })
}
shouldThrow(checkCyclic, grodzi1, grodzi2, grodziNoCopy, grodziStopVisit, grodziIter)

for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  bench(checkCyclic, 'cyclic')
  bench(grodzi1, 'grodzi1')
  bench(grodzi2, 'grodzi2')
  bench(grodziNoCopy, 'grodziNoCopy')
  bench(grodziStopVisit, 'grodziStopVisit')
  bench(grodziIter, 'grodziIter')
  console.log('next')
}
```

Comment: Love the first implementation as it is clean and simple. And yes, from a performance perspective keeping a reference to the visited nodes makes a lot of sense. However the code starts looking ugly.

I went ahead and added an iterative implementation to the question above. Even more gruesome and I'm not sure it's salvageable. 

Waiting a little while but, might accept your question if no one else wants to take a stab at it!

Comment: Just did a performance test and it looks like your second implementation is still ~10 times slower than both of mine. My iterative beats my recursive by a little bit as would be expected. Running short on time to investigate more, but here is the test setup: https://github.com/blackflux/promise-pool-ext/pull/199/files

Comment: I have edited post @vincent I don't reproduce your 10x time slower. I only find that they (at least what we propose) are equivalent

Comment: Your bench function doesn't call fn? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Gettingrid of cold start bias I get >>> cyclic: 16.032ms grodzi1: 891.510ms grodzi2: 3165.083ms grodziNoCopy: 1001.035ms grodziStopVisit: 22.204ms <<< ---- grodziIter crashes

Comment: Damned me indeed forgot to replace. Will have a look

Comment: On my hand I have concluded that I can't do better that your algorithm. Popping one child by one seems to be the fastest. You should probably answer and accept your own answer if noone proposes better @vincent

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. The original question was around readability. And the best performing algorithm is not very readable :) And regarding correctness question see test suite in linked project.